# SQL Indexing for search

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, indexing

Lets say I got this table in mysql

```
ID Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
```

ID column is primary key others can either be a foreign key or no key at all.

Any combination of those columns could be used in `WHERE` statement when searching. For example the user could be asking for the result `where Col1 = 1 and Col3 = 100` | OR something like `Col2 = 10 and Col3 < 1000 and Col4 > 0`

Table is updated frequently as user do post/delete/modification. How should I index this table to speed up the search time as this table could grow quite large with time.

I am currently using MySQL, but would be ideal if the answer doesn't limited to MySQL since I might want to move it to SQL Server some day

Comment: How large is "*quite large*"? Millions of records? More?

Comment: @PM77-1 sorry about previous comment, could be couple millions yes. If possible please explain what would be different if it is couple hundred thousands or its couple million

Comment: @PM77-1 Sorry I got my unit wrong .... It could be couple millions. expecting it to be under 20million but I don't have an oracle to see the future

Comment: I would create 4 separate indexes (on each column) and using the inflated table (with max expected records) see how much search speed improves and/or CRUD speed degrades.

Comment: @PM77-1 Well since its about indexing, I would need to know the distribution to simulate it rite, if I just make all Col1 = 1 then the search would go incredibly fast if I do something like Col1 = 0 and (...). The problem is I don't know what is going to be the distribution for values

Comment: In this case wait till it gets close to becominge an issue by monitoring the performance.

Comment: You may also decide to move this question to [`DBA` site](http://dba.stackexchange.com) (or ask moderators to do it for you).

Comment: Index it according to the data volumes and to the actual queries run  by the users. If you can show us the value distributions in the columns and the frequencies of different queries that are run against the table, we can possibly suggest indexes. Otherwise, just create indexes that seem probable and watch for performance problems.

Comment: @user2338816 the application is still under development, so IDK about the distribution..But I guess I can always add/remove index on the fly

Comment: Yep, that's about the scope of it. The point is that if **you** don't know the details, it's guaranteed that we don't know. _Appropriate_ indexing can be almost an art. It is highly related to the actual live environment and can change as the environment changes. Give it your best guess, and come back here when it isn't making good sense after it's live.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If any combination of columns can be used in the WHERE clause, and every combination is equally likely, you probably won't do better than creating four indexes, one on each column.

But, in the real world, every combination is almost certainly *not* equally likely. You can approach that in two different ways. (Not counting the one above.)

1. Create *no* indexes, and wait for people to complain about performance. Then create indexes relevant to the complaints. (But some people will suffer rather than complain.)
2. [Log all the queries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-log.html), and create indexes based on the actual distribution of columns used in the WHERE clauses.

Having a great many indexes takes up space, but space is cheap nowadays. I think the only risk is in possibly confusing the query optimizer.